# how to change color of textView of custom griditem in android

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-gridview, listitem

I have made a custom calender in android,I have used a custom grid View for this,Now i want to change the color of selected date from the calender,But i don't know how to do this,My code is as below,I am attaching custom grid Item and java code.Please help needed.thank you.

**Grid_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_cell"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#545454"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/date_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**code**

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
            selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString.get(position);
            String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
            String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                    "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
            int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
            // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
            if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);

            showToast(selectedGridDate);

        }
    });
```

Comment: `setOnItemClickListener` is the correct function to implement I feel sagar is correct.

Comment: @android-mantra-yes and its working but i just wanted to change the color of selected item,so previously selected textview should be as it is as before.hope you get me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private TextView txtDate;
....
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
            //add your code here
            if(txtDate!=null)
            {
              txtDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); // the color you want for unselected date
            }
            txtDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
            txtDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E5AC56")); // the color you want for selected date
            .....
            .....                   
        }
    });
```

Comment: its a textView inside GridItem..how can i do like this sagar?

Comment: in my activity there is no onActivityREsult method..!i have tried as edit..but it changes the color of all the dates once selected

Comment: all the days i select gets white...i just want the only selected date text white...!

Comment: sagar thank you bro.its working..but now currentdate remains white .when i again select it and unselect it..then only it gets red..get my problem?

Comment: instead of `#000000` you might have given `Color.RED`, give the default color which you are seeing in your calender.

Answer (score 1):

at your custom adapter add the below code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    TextView dayView;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout, null);

    }
    dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
    // separates daystring into parts.
    String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
    // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
    String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
    // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
    if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
        // setting offdays to white color.
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        dayView.setClickable(false);
        dayView.setFocusable(false);
    } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        dayView.setClickable(false);
        dayView.setFocusable(false);
    } else {
        // setting curent month's days in blue color.
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
        setSelected(v);
        previousView = v;
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
    }
    dayView.setText(gridvalue);

    // create date string for comparison
    String date = dayString.get(position);

    if (date.length() == 1) {
        date = "0" + date;
    }
    String monthStr = "" + (month.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
        monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
    }

    // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array
    ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
    if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(date)) {
        iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


    return v;
}

public View setSelected(View view) {
    if (previousView != null) {
        previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
    }
    previousView = view;
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cel_selectl);
    return view;
}
```